# How to Insert blob data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I want to insert blob data into MySQL database. I am aware of `LOAD_FILE` but it's not fitting my requirements. Also tried inserting hex value:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, x'6210341GG80JF803080G40GG2000000000002400000000001GO0K1G85A34HJHT0G1G4C0Q645J02860DAG82OC08O3EC8B604GC0QL0G1GO0');
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: when querying it fails

Answer (score 1):

Use a valid hex value. The value in the question is not valid.

I also suggest that you remove the single quotes and add zero before the `x`:

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 0x6210341fab6210341);
```

Comment: I am getting this error - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: That's because the value you have is not hex value. I copied it from your question thinking it was correct and didn't pay attention. Hex values only include a-f characters, but your other invalid characters like G, K. O, Q, etc. Where did you get that value from? Use a valid hex value and query will work.